# Should I use a sprite(image) or should I draw?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Below is a screenshot from a famous structure building game.

[image]

As you can see rods are attached together with ball joints. I'm trying to achieve something similar with Cosos2d on iPhone. I've got two questions here:

1. Should I draw those ball joints or should I just add them as sprites?
2. I guess the rods are not drawn bur are rather images. But considering that the length of the rods will change depending on need, how do I make rods with different lengths from just one image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what would be the best approach for one. I would imagine that either way would be fine, but it would be harder to achieve whatever visual affect you want through drawing them. I think the hardest part would be making sure that they are anchored to vertices in a grid system that has the dimension that you want.

As for (2) you can always scale your image.

```
     CCSprite *rod = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rod.png"];
     rod.scaleY = 2.0; //or scaleX
```

Then rotate and change its anchor points as needed.

Again I imagine the most difficult part would be anchoring them and positioning them correctly, so that align properly with the vertices.

Comment: Hmmm, nice help. So scaleY would drag something by its height(or width) and scaleX vice-versa

Comment: Yes, it stretches the image. This wouldn't look very good if your image had any details, but if it had a fairly uniform texture (like a rod) I think it would look fine. You would also have to make sure to give the joints a larger z:(int), so that they are drawn on top. ie.         [self addChild:joint z:10 tag:jointTag];